# Getting my tomcat app to show up on port 80 on MediaTemple

Tags: tomcat, vps

My boss just switched her web hosting to MediaTemple VPS (in spite of my recommendation of Linode or Panix).  I've got everything running now except for one thing - the app only shows up on port 8080.  Does anybody know how to set up a mod_proxy or mod_jk redirect on MediaTemple so that it will show up on `http://<our domain>/foo?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is what I had to do:

The file `~/conf/httpd.include` for the domain said that you could put things in `~/conf/vhost.conf`, but that didn't work.  Anything I put in there was apparently not read or recognized, and nothing appeared in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` to say why, so I suspect the file wasn't read at all.  On the other hand, trying to do a "ProxyPass" in `~/httpdocs/.htaccess` got a server failure, with a notice in error_log saying that you can't do that there.  Then I discovered that `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` had a file called "`proxy_ajp_conf`" which had some commented out some ProxyPass commands.  Putting a directive in there did what I wanted.  The only downside is that it does it for all domains on this host, not just the one I wanted it for.  But that's minor.

```
ProxyPass /foo ajp://localhost:8009/foo
```